# Boundary Value Condition error bvp4c

Tags: matlab, equation, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation using the bvp4c function (using boundary value conditions [0 0 1.2][2 2 1.2]) but i always get the error "In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same. " i dont know why this error happens ?

```
init = bvpinit(linspace(0,2,10),[0 0 0]);
sol = bvp4c(@Kpath1,@bcpath,init);
t = linspace(0,2,100);
BS = deval(sol,t);
plot(t,BS(1,:))
function bv = bcpath(L,R)
bv = [L(1)   L(2)  L(3)-1.2; R(1)-2 R(2)-2 R(3)-1.2];
end
function dt = Kpath1(~,c)
        L = 0.12;                        
        r = 0.1;
        WL = 0.25;WR = 0.25;
          x = c(1);y = c(2);th = c(3);
          dx = (((r*WL)+(r*WR))/2) * cos(th);
          dy = (((r*WL)+(r*WR))/2) * sin(th);
          dth= ((r*WR)-(r*WL))/L;
          dt = [dx;dy;dth];
          pose = [x y th];
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the BVP you're trying to solve?  A third-order BVP only needs three boundary conditions, but you're inputing six as if it were a two-region, second-order problem.

Comment: the thing is i have a system of 3 equations [x,y,theta] which are a function of time(t), there are boundary conditions at time (t) = 0, [0 0 1.2] and at time (t) = 2,[2 2 1.2] how can this be written in only a 3*1 vector ?

Comment: I changed the initial value system into a boundary value problem, from dydt and dxdt and dthetadt into dydx and dthetadx using the chain rule and it worked fone :) thanks again